# Combine tags "loan" and "loans"?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I think that we should combine the tags "loan" and "loans". Loans is currently much more popular

Comment: I agree.  Tags merge & synonym created.

Answer (score 1):

I agree. I put the suggestion in, people just need to vote on it now.